# Ruby regex for string that contains exactly x amount of integers

Tags: regex, ruby, string, integer

I want to craft a ruby regex that matches strings that contain exactly x integer numbers. I want the string to also be able to contain other words as well.

Example:
If **x = 2**, the following should match:
**"There were 3 cars going over 45 miles per hour"**

where the first integer is 3 and the second integer is 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the general regex pattern:

```regex
^\D*(?:\d+\D+){2}$
```

You may replace the `{2}` with however many numbers you expect in the string.  Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqBwXr/2).

Comment: You almost never want `^` and `$` in a Ruby regex, `\A` and `\z` (respectively) are almost always what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would write

```
str = "There were 3 cars going over 45 miles per hour"
```

```
str.scan(/\d+/).size == 2
  #=> true
```

or

```
str.gsub(/\d+/).count == 2
  #=> true
```

The latter has the advantage that `str.gsub(/\d+)` returns an enumerator, whereas `str.scan(/\d+/)` creates a temporary array.

See the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes an argument but no block, and [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).